# could you hep me to explain this part of code please?

Tags: java

its about break with label, java programming. This program searches for the number 1 in an array.

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] arrayOfInts =
        {{  32,     87,     3,      589},
        {   12,     1076,   2000,   8},
        {   622,    127,    77,     955}};

        int searchfor = 1;

        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;
        boolean foundIt = false;

        search:
        for (; i < arrayOfInts.length; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < arrayOfInts[i].length; j++){
                if (arrayOfInts [i][j] == searchfor) {
                    foundIt = true;
                    break search;
                }
            }
        }
        if (foundIt) {
            System.out.println("Found "+ searchfor + " at " + i +", "+ j);
        } else {
            System.out.println(searchfor + " not in the array");
        }
    }
}
```

the part of code that i didnt understand is

```
search:
        for (; i < arrayOfInts.length; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < arrayOfInts[i].length; j++){
                if (arrayOfInts [i][j] == searchfor) {
                    foundIt = true;
                    break search;
                }
            }
        }
```

and why there is ";" in front of "i"??

Comment: This means, you are using variable, which you declared and initialized before `int i = 0;`

Comment: Is the question what the label `search:` and the `break search;` means or why there is no statement inside the first part of the `for(...; ...; ...);` loop?

Comment: @Progman what is label search: and the break search; means is also one of my question :) and what's this steatment call

Comment: @MBS `break` and `continue` will usually work only on the loop it is placed in. But when you use `break someLabel;` you are saying: "I want to stop **THAT** `for` loop" and the execution continues after the `for` loop block. This only makes sense when you are nesting loops like you have in your question.

Comment: @MBS Can you accept one of the below answers or explain why those answers doesn't work?

Answer (score 2):

It's just an another way of writing for loop.

As `i` is initialised outside before the for loop, there is no initialisation required in for loop.

Code 1:

```
for(int i=0;i<n;i++){}
```

Code 2:

```
int i=0;
for(;i<n;i++){}
```

The Code 1 and Code 2 mean the same thing.

Comment: They don't quite mean the same: `i` has a different scope between the two. In the second case, you can use `i` after the loops; in the first case you can't.

Answer (score 2):

For loop to `(<intialize counter>;<check loop condition>;<modify counter>)`
In you first for loop there is nothing to initialize hence ;

```
or (; i < arrayOfInts.length; i++) { // Selects i'th row of your array
            for (j = 0; j < arrayOfInts[i].length; j++){ // Scans array by j'th column of the i'th row
                if (arrayOfInts [i][j] == searchfor) { // matches the i'th row and j'th column value of the array 
                    foundIt = true;
                    break search; // comes out of the column for loop
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the format of the for loop. The `initialization`, `termindation`, and `increment` part can be blank.

```
for (initialization; termination; increment) {
    statement(s)
}
```

In your code example, `i` was initialized before the for loop.

It will be similar to this:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] arrayOfInts = {{1,2}, {3, 4}};
    int searchfor = 8;
    boolean foundIt = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < arrayOfInts.length; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < arrayOfInts[i].length; j++){
        if (arrayOfInts [i][j] == searchfor) {
          foundIt = true;
          break;
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

See: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html

Comment: All three parts can be blank: `for(;;) { statements }` is legal.

Comment: @AndyTurner Thanks for the insight. I've updated the answer to make it better. :)